# gnome system monitor save timeline

Tags: gnome, system-monitoring

Im using gnome system monitor and I like the graphic it shows. The thing is that I would like to record that graphic for about an hour or maybe a day so I have a complete view of how my system performs during that time.

Can someone help me on how to save that graphic information or at least the information?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first save your necessary information by using `dstat`, which can be easily installed by `sudo apt-get install dstat` and is easy in use. For instance, if you want to monitor CPU, load average, memory usage and network statistics you can use

`dstat -cdlmn >1`

and the information would be written to file 1 every second. You'll have at about 7Mb file for the day which is rather big. To change the period of time of data saving, use

```
dstat -cdlmn -tc N >1
```

where N is the period in seconds. Then you can plot the data using for example `gnuplot`. You can look an example of using `gnuplot` with output of `dstat` here (http://niftybits.wordpress.com/2008/03/28/gnuplot-dstat-easy-graphing-on-linux/).

Comment: If you want a timeline view, you can also use https://sealion.com where you have graphs for system metrics like CPU, memory etc. Also you can schedule your own commands like `dstat` to see the data in a convenient timeline.